# How can I stop admob from spamming my logcat?

Tags: android, admob

Ads on my add output so much data to `logcat`. how can I stop the ads from printing to `logcat`?

Comment: Couldn't you just filter it out of logcat?

Comment: @JeffS I have it filtered to only show my application but the log messages seem to be coming from my application

Comment: Don't they have a specific tag that can help you filter them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter that I have found that works best in Eclipse to filter out unwanted messages, even ones generated by the application is:

```
^(?!.*(text_to_filter_out_here)).*$
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you don't have to put the full text in the (), part of it is fine. Enough so that it filters out the admob stuff but not other stuff that may have the same sequence of characters.