# How to hide, remove, filter logs in the logcat in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I had some difficulties finding the right post for hiding logs in Eclipse for Android (maybe because of the keywords of the subject), that's why I created one. Here is the post I found : (look at ZoFreX's answer, the simplest)

[How to exclude certain messages by TAG name using Android adb logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511433/how-to-exclude-certain-messages-by-tag-name-using-android-adb-logcat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filter that I have found to work the best for me is:

```
^(?!.*(text_to_filter_out_here)).*$
```

This works for anything from my experience. I have threads that run infinite loops creating a ton of spam logs that aren't associated with and tags so I just put in part of the log message in the `text_to_filter_out_here` part and no more logs appear.

Also possible duplicate of these two:

[How can I stop admob from spamming my logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705195/how-can-i-stop-admob-from-spamming-my-logcat/15705307#15705307)

[How to filter out a tagname in Eclipse LogCat viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer)

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to work the same. Do you know the difference between the two expressions? There must be one I guess

Comment: My guess is that the other is for Tags only, while I know that this can be used to filter out system generated messages that have no tag associated with them. From my experience this has worked better for me and seems a little more powerful becuase it can filter out system logs.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be (for the moment) no explicit way to hide some logs (from 'libgps' for example). To hide posts which tags are 'tag_1' and 'tag_2', click on the green plus and fill the 'by log Tag' field with :

```
^(?!(tag_1|tag_2))
```

And so on if you want to add some tags to hide

Hope this will be helpful