# my phone does not show exception message

Tags: android, exception, android-studio-2.3, huawei-mobile-services

I am a new android developer and sorry for my poor English, I got a new phone (Huawei 6X). When I debug with my phone android studio it doesn't show my exception message and always shows this:

```
`06-03 15:21:40.668 2077-14971/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=1628, uid=10028 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10028 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1599)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforcePermission(ContextImpl.java:1612)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforcePermission(ContextWrapper.java:664)
                                                     at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.checkPermission(LauncherProvider.java:1615)
                                                     at com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.call(LauncherProvider.java:1854)
                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:398)
                                                     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:283)
                                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
06-03 15:21:40.671 1628-6300/? E/LauncherInteractiveUtil: Call launcher evnt fail. lock=true
                                                          java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=1628, uid=10028 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10028 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:437)
                                                              at com.huawei.keyguard.support.LauncherInteractiveUtil$Caller.run(LauncherInteractiveUtil.java:59)
                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)`
```

When I try with another phone android studio shows exception message correctly. Please help me.

ps: My phone doesn't show "unfortunately your app is close" message either ... it just close the app.

Comment: there are some device in which you cannot get proper logs as system logs flood them badly. Try using emulator or filter log by certain tags

Comment: you can use regex to filter all the  unwanted logs like dalvik and other system manager log via regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017479/5028508